# Extract record based on time value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQLServer 2016 and I have the table (TIMETABLE) with the follow data:

| ID | Descrizione | OraInizio | OraFine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Morning | 06:00:00 | 13:00:00 |
| 2 | Afternoon | 13:00:01 | 19:00:00 |
| 3 | Night | 19:00:01 | 05:59:59 |

Now I need to extract the ID from this table using a datetime so I wrote this query:

```
DECLARE @DATA AS DATETIME = '11-09-2023 00:30:00'
SELECT * 
FROM TIMETABLE
WHERE Convert(time(2), Convert(smalldatetime, @DATA)) BETWEEN ORAINIZIO AND ORAFINE
```

Now this query is not working: it should extract ID = 3 because time 00:30 is in the Night range.

How can I change my query to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into account cases when `ORAINIZIO >= ORAFINE` and therefore the times are reversed.

You also shouldn't use `BETWEEN` for comparisons, [as noted here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). Instead use `>= AND <`.

```sql
DECLARE @DATA AS DATETIME = '2023-09-11 00:30:00';
DECLARE @tim time(2) = CONVERT(time(2), @DATA);

SELECT * 
FROM TIMETABLE
WHERE (ORAINIZIO < ORAFINE  AND @tim >= ORAINIZIO AND @tim < ORAFINE)
   OR (ORAINIZIO >= ORAFINE AND (@tim < ORAFINE OR @tim >= ORAINIZIO);
```

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that you are seeing `time` as a cyclical value. You're seeing `13:00:00` as greater than `06:00:00` but also `06:00:00` is *greater* than `19:00:00`. A `time` represents a *time of day*, so the *greatest* value would be `23:59:59.9999999`.

You'll need to use some `OR` logic here to check of the end time is greater than the start time or not. If it isn't greater you need to check if the parameter is *greater* than the start time or *less than* the end time:

```sql
DECLARE @DATA AS time(0) = '2023-09-11T00:30:00' --The date will be truncated

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(1,'Morning  ',CONVERT(time(0),'06:00:00'),CONVERT(time(0),'13:00:00')), --Use full boundaries and >=/> and </< logic
            (2,'Afternoon',CONVERT(time(0),'13:00:00'),CONVERT(time(0),'19:00:00')),
            (3,'Night    ',CONVERT(time(0),'19:00:00'),CONVERT(time(0),'06:00:00')))V(ID,Descrizione,OraInizio,OraFine)
WHERE (OraInizio < OraFine AND OraInizio < @Data AND OraFine >= @DATA)
   OR (OraInizio > OraFine AND (OraInizio > @DATA OR OraFine <= @DATA));
```